How to use external location while storing DLT tables (Delta Live tables ) using UC?
I am currently using hive meta store to store my data in external Storage location but when we using Unity catalog With DLT (delta Live Table)
@dlt.table(
comment="New raw data incrementally ingested from ADLS Gen2 cloud object storage landing/Raw zone",
path=f"{bronze_output_delta_folder_path}",
name=f"{fileName}",
partition_cols = partitionArray,
temporary = True
)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot specify an explicit path for a table when using Unity Catalog. Remove the explicit path: abfss:/abc/commercial-bronze-layer/delta/Masterdata/Customer/MDG///0CUSTOMER_ATTR/  set for table 0customer_attr.
When i remove path its storing the table as a streaming table

To use an external location while storing Delta Live Tables (DLT) using Unity Catalog, you should not specify an explicit path for the table. When using Unity Catalog, the path to the table is managed by the catalog, and specifying an explicit path can cause errors. Instead, you should create the table without specifying a path, and the table will be created in the Unity Catalog. Here is an example of creating a DLT table with Unity Catalog.
